# Как правильно 'перехватить' событие?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, события

У меня есть *div*, в котором распологаются *img* и *a*. Нужно вызвать событие при клике по любой области этого элемента: и по пустой, и по тем, где расположены другие элементы. Но получилось так, что *a* вызывает событие раньше чем *div*, что делает работу события некоректной. Как сделать *div* единственным объектом события с помощью JQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').on('click', event);
});

function event(ev) {
  alert(ev.target.nodeName);
  $(ev.target).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="" alt="image">
  <br>
  <a>Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: alert(ev.currentTarget.nodeName);

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: Не по теме: почитайте о зарезервированных словах в языках программирования.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, воспользовался способом с данной статьи, но теперь при клике над 'a' ничего не происходит. При клике на пустую область 'div' и 'img' всё работает.

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _делает работу события некорректной_?

Comment: @Grundy, когда я нажимаю по 'div', он должен поменять цвет фона. Но 'a' перехватывает событие на себя и препятствует этому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что требуется в конечном итоге получить, но на сколько я понял, речь идет о "перехвате", чего конечно же нет, просто `event.target` возвращает непосредственный элемент с которым происходит взаимодействие, в отличии от `event.currentTarget` или `this`, который в свою очередь являются ссылкой на элемент к которому привязан слушатель.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').on('click', event);
});

function event(ev) {
  console.log('currentTarget: ', ev.currentTarget.nodeName);
  console.log('this: ', this.nodeName);
  console.log('target: ', ev.target.nodeName);
  $(ev.currentTarget).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="" alt="image">
  <br>
  <a>Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').on('click', event);
});

function event(ev) {
  $(this).addClass('active'); // this !!!
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="" alt="image">
  <br>
  <a>Text</a>
</div>
```